# Check the class of something in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning clojure and have a very basic question: given that clojure has type inference, how can you tell what class was inferred?

For instance, these would each result in different data types:

```
(2)
(/ 2 3)
(/ 2.0 3)
```

Is there some kind of `class` function that will return the data type?  Also, is there a normal way of casting something to be a specific type?  So in the second example above, what would I do if I wanted the result to be float?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a `type` function in the `clojure.core` library.

```
user> (type 2)
java.lang.Integer

user> (type (/ 2 3))
clojure.lang.Ratio

user> (type (/ 2.0 3))
java.lang.Double
```

If you want to convert a given number into a float then use `float`.

```
user> (float 10)
10.0
```

Comment: Dang! `type` is not on the Clojure Cheat Sheet ( <http://clojure.org/cheatsheet> ) so I didn't find it :(

Comment: There is also `class`. `type` basically checks the metadata (if any) first for the :type key. Then as fallback `class` is used.

Comment: Very true! It also very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly you may not need to cast because the following works:

```
user> (Double/toString (/ 2 3))
"0.6666666666666667"
```

However, this does too:

```
user> (str (/ 2 3))
"0.6666666666666667"
```